# Which mobile wallets that let you change your owner and active keys?

Tags: keys, public-key, android, ios

What are some android and iOS wallets that let you change your owner and active keys by pasting in the new public key?

Comment: You can create it yourself becuase you can change active key as well as owner key if you have owner key, Here is an example https://eostoolkit.io/account/permissions .For more info please refer EOS documentation